# What's the use of ~기 in sentences?

Tags: spoken-korean, korean-to-english

So I learnt that we add 기 to verbs to make them nouns. I know that some structures require verbs to be changed to nouns like ~때문에 but what is/are the actual use(s) and need of this addition? Please list some example sentences too.

Comment: To express a reason why something happens, verbs have to be converted to noun form, such as `-기`.

Answer (score 1):

Just like 'because of-' in English, 때문에 must come after a noun. As you already know, to change a verb into a noun, you need -기 after the verb.

ex) 숙제 때문에 스트레스 받아서 죽을 것 같아 (숙제 + 때문에)

아빠는 요즘 일 때문에 너무 바쁘시다 (일 + 때문에)

이게 다 너 때문이야 (너 + 때문)

널 사랑하기 때문에 이렇게 도와주는 거야 (사랑하다 + -기 = 사랑하기)

지금은 봄이기 때문에 날씨가 좋은 거야 (봄이다 + -기 = 봄이기)

모든 사람들의 생각이 똑같을 수 없기 때문에 갈등이 일어난다 (똑같을 수 없다 + -기 = 똑같을 수 없기)

Comment: I am sorry my question doesn't seem clear(English is not my first language) .. I intended to ask that beside some structures which require verbs to be changed to nouns, is there any other use?

Comment: @ieycha https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/do-i-use-the-%ed%95%b4%eb%9d%bc%ec%b2%b4-for-personal-notes