# Do I use the 해라체 for personal notes?

Tags: grammar, written, conjugation

I know that the 해라체 is used in diaries, books, newspapers and so forth, but is it also used for casual personal notes to myself? Like "water the flowers" or statements like "password is 123".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s okay to use 해라체 in personal notes but in general it isn’t preferred. They’d rather write sentences without 상대 높임법 applied. A way to do that is to use 명사형 종결어미 like `~기` or `~음` which makes the sentence sound very neutral.

Afaik the most common form in 'TODO' sentences is `~하기`. I also use it myself in my personal notes. For example,

- `화분에 물 주기`: Water the flowers.
- `빨래 널기`: Do the laundry.
- `일찍 일어나기`: Wake up early.

And I’d use `~음` for any sentence that simply states facts or observations.

- `날씨 맑음`: It’s sunny.
- `날씨가 흐림`: It’s cloudy.
- `암호는 123임`: Password is 123.
- `열쇠는 상자 안에 있음`: The key is in the box.
- `적에게 기습 공격 받음`: The enemy made a surprise attack.

Comment: Sometimes we don't even bother writing the verbs when it is obvious from the context. For example, some likes to write just 화분(에) 물 and omit 주기. Of course you can use whichever form you like, since it is personal. But if you want to make up some personal notes as a part of fiction or other types of writing that you want to show others, then Coconut's examples are the standard ways to do it.

Comment: @Absol I don't want to be picky, but I have to correct that comment as it's now getting upvoted... No, Coconut's examples here are not the standard ways to do it. With those examples I was just trying to show how statements are styled using 명사형 종결어미. Also please note that the form is in common usage for any statement that is not necessarily made for fictions or showing off, and especially amongst people who get to schedule their stuff often. Good examples can be found on Github: https://github.com/ordidxzero/react-native-todo-calendar https://github.com/jokh0108/Todo